# A simple parametric function whose shape can be tweaked

Tags: analysis, functions

I am looking for a simple parametric function $f(x; a)$ that is defined on the closed interval $x\in [0,1]$. On this interval the function should be non-negative, and have an integral of $1$, regardless of the parameter value. I would like it to correspond to constant $1$ for some parameter value, but for other choices it should vary continuously between "frontloaded" (majority of the integral comes from the first half of the interval) and "backloded" (the opposite).

A trivial example would be

$$f(x;a) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & \mathrm{if\ } a = 0 \\
      1/(1-a) & \mathrm{if\ } 0 < a < 1 \mathrm{\ and\ } x \geq a\\
      0 & \mathrm{if\ } 0 < a < 1 \mathrm{\ and\ } x < a\\
      1/(1+a) & \mathrm{if\ } -1 < a < 0 \mathrm{\ and\ } x \leq -a\\
      0 & \mathrm{if\ } -1 < a < 0 \mathrm{\ and\ } x > -a\\
   \end{cases}
$$

However, this is only continuous in the parameter $a$, not in the variable $x$.

I would welcome any suggestions for how to do better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider the family of ["beta densities"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) defined for $x \in [0,1]$ with 2 parameters $a,b>0$ :

$$f_{a,b}(x)={\frac {\Gamma (a+b)}{\Gamma (a)\Gamma (b)}}\,x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}$$

Their integral on this interval is $1$ and can vary from "frontloaded" to "backloaded".

[image]

In order to have a unique parameter, you can make $a,b$ as functions of a common parameter $t$ : here, we have taken $a=4t, \ b=4-2t$.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to create a dependence on this variable $t$ such that there is flat curve for some value of $t$.

Comment: Thanks Jean Marie, I have been thinking if something similar. This is a good start. I didn’t specify that in the question, but of in addition for fixed a we could have a function that is monotonic in x (increasing or decreasing) that would be even better. I wonder if we could tweak this accordingly. EDIT: On second thought maybe it’s enough to just make sure either a or b is zero to do that.

Comment: I have a solution : take $y=f(x;a)=a(2x-1)+1$ for $-1\le a \le 1$ with the particular case  $a=0$ in which you get the constant function $y=1$ ... All these straight lines have a common point $M(\tfrac12,1)$.

Comment: Yes, I think I will combine the two ideas into something like $y\sim [a(2x-1)+1]^b$ and that will do all that I want, with the right normalization. Thanks for helping me think this through!

Comment: Happy this is helpful for you. Thanks for your thanks.